# Is it possible to create mock data using pydantic-factories in such a way that attributes adhere to pydantic validator requirements?

Tags: python, validation, attributes, factory, pydantic

I'm trying to create some mock data, where one of my classes (for which I specified a Pydantic dataclass by inheriting from `Pydantic.BaseModel`) has date attributes. I want to make sure that the `end_date` is always later than the `start_date`, and validate this using the pydantic validator decorator:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from datetime import datetime


class Dates(BaseModel):
    start_date: datetime
    end_date: datetime

    @validator('end_date')
    def ensure_end_date_is_after_start_date(cls, end_date, values):

        if not end_date > values['start_date']:
            raise ValueError(f"End date {end_date} is not after start date {values['start_date']}.")
        return end_date
```

Suppose that I now want to create some mock data, using the `pydantic_factories` package. I define a class that inherits from `ModelFactory` to later create some mock data.

```
from pydantic_factories import ModelFactory


ModelFactory.seed_random(0)


class DatesFactory(ModelFactory):
    __model__ = Dates
```

However, in this fashion, I have no guarantee that `start_date` will be before `end_date`. I set `ModelFactory.seed_random(0)`, to get reproducible results. And indeed, when I create my mock data, I see that the date validation failed:

```
my_dates = DatesFactory()
my_dates.build()
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Dates
end_date
  End date 2006-06-21 01:20:01 is not after start date 2022-02-03 12:04:21. (type=value_error)
```

**My question**: How do I make sure that I get mock data that adheres to my validation criteria? What is the usual way to go about this in a way that is extensible to more complex validations?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The current example may be a bit silly; I am aware it could be circumvented by defining my attributes differently (e.g. define only `start_date` and an always positive `duration`). This example is, however, something that I would like to extend to something a bit more complex.

Complete MWE:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic_factories import ModelFactory


class Dates(BaseModel):
    start_date: datetime
    end_date: datetime

    @validator('end_date')
    def ensure_end_date_is_after_start_date(cls, end_date, values):

        if not end_date > values['start_date']:
            raise ValueError(f"End date {end_date} is not after start date {values['start_date']}.")
        return end_date


class DatesFactory(ModelFactory):
    __model__ = Dates

ModelFactory.seed_random(0)

my_dates = DatesFactory()
my_dates.build()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation [here](https://polyfactory.litestar.dev/reference/factories/pydantic_factory.html#polyfactory.factories.pydantic_factory.ModelFactory.build), by
setting `factory_use_construct` to true `.build()` method will omit running validation.

> **factory_use_construct – A boolean** that determines whether validations will be made when instantiating the model. This is supported only for pydantic models.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pydantic_factories import ModelFactory


class Dates(BaseModel):
    start_date: datetime
    end_date: datetime

    @validator('end_date')
    def ensure_end_date_is_after_start_date(cls, end_date, values):

        if not end_date > values['start_date']:
            raise ValueError(f"End date {end_date} is not after start date {values['start_date']}.")
        return end_date


class DatesFactory(ModelFactory[Dates]):
    __model__ = Dates

factory_result = DatesFactory(factory_use_construct=True)
print(factory.dict())

>>> {'start_date': datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 24, 3, 16, 28), 'end_date': datetime.datetime(1994, 11, 1, 14, 50, 48)}
```

Or by specifying default values for `start_date` and `end_date`,

> **kwargs – Any kwargs**. If field_meta names are set in kwargs, their values will be used.

```py
start_date = datetime.now()                                                                                    
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=5)                                                                
                                                                                                                     
fields_meta = {"start_date": start_date, "end_date": end_date}                                                 
factory_result = DatesFactory.build(**fields_meta) 

# To make sure your data is valid
factory_result.validate(factory_result.dict())
```

**N.B:** The next version of `pydantic-factories 1.17.3` is released as `polyfactory`

Comment: Hi farch, thank you for your comment. Your solution isn't quite what I am looking for though: it seems to describe ways to _circumvent_ the validation, instead of creating actual random attributes that _adhere to_ the validation. I appreciate your input, but I'm looking for ways to generate random dates where `start_date < end_date`, always.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be the first to admit this isn't perfectly satisfying but in complicated cases like this we've taken to customizing the generator method on required fields to enforce compliance rules. In your case, you could do something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from polyfactory.factories.pydantic_factory import ModelFactory
from polyfactory.decorators import post_generated
import random

class DatesFactory(ModelFactory):
    __model__ = Dates

    @post_generated
    @classmethod
    def end_date(cls, start_date: datetime) -> datetime:
        """ """
        return start_date + timedelta(days=random.randint(1, 1000))
```

The `post_generated` annotation gives us access to fields like `start_date` defined on the base model. From there you'll be able to define whatever customization logic is necessary for your use-case.

You can overwrite implementations for each field without the annotation as well but won't have access to the other factory fields.